# angular how to display key in json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I have the following JSON array of objects :

```
"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"}, 
    {"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}
]
```

and i want to get a specific key in JSON array :

```
for (var ke in employees) {
       if (employees.hasOwnProperty(ke)) {
             console.log(employees[ke].lastName);
       };
```

but it does not work !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a closing curly bracket at the end of your for loop, it should be:

```
for (var ke in employees) {
   if (employees.hasOwnProperty(ke)) {
         console.log(employees[ke].lastName);
   };
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly7zb8oq/1/)

However, you could use [angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) instead, like this:

```
angular.forEach(employees, function (ke) {
    if(ke.lastName) {
        console.log(ke.lastName);
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0unxf6xk/1/)

Answer (score 2):

When traversing through Javascript arrays, use the standard [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop rather than [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

```
for (var i=0; i < employees.length; i+=1) {
    console.log(employees[i].lastname);
}
```

Alternatively, ES5 now provides an [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function that could be used as well.

```
employees.forEach( function (employee) { 
  console.log(employee.lastname);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
for (var index in employees) {
    var tp = employees[index];
    console.log(tp['yourkeyhere']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Approach: 1** - With more validation.

```
var employees= [
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"}, 
    {"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}
];

for(var obj in employees) {
    if(employees.hasOwnProperty(obj)){
        for(var prop in employees[obj]){
            if(employees[obj].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
                alert(prop + ' : ' + employees[obj][prop]);
                //to change the key's value
                if(employees[obj][prop] == 'Smith'){
                    employees[obj][prop]='Mike';
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xxBx9pw5Vudmzd6NPbKy?p=preview)

**Approach: 2** Without validation (not recommended)

```
   for(i in employees) {
       var obj = employees[i];
       for(j in obj) {
           var key = j;
           var val = obj[j];
           alert(key + " : " + val);   
       }
    }
```

**Edit:**

```
var employees={"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"};
Object.keys(employees); // return ["firstName", "lastName"]
```

`Object` has a `prototype` `keys`, returns an `Array` of `keys` in an `Object`

Chrome, FF & Safari supports `Object.keys`

Comment: You should consider decouple each for, you are having a complexity of 1n (1 for  a lot of fors) you can create a map if you want to iterate trough objs inside an object, but in this case there are no need for doing that. a plain for with Object.keys should work perfectly.

Comment: you want to change key or value for lastName?

Comment: i want to change value

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to the following.
It works correctly.

```
employees=[
        {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
        {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"}, 
        {"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}
    ]
    for(var ke in employees) {
           if (employees.hasOwnProperty(ke)) {
                 console.log(employees[ke].lastName);
           };
   }
```